# How to create a SAS dataset for each individual trading day (TAQ) data and save them to a file

Tags: sas, gzip, unzip

I have the daily trading data (TAQ data) for a month. I am trying to unzip each of them.
The folder's name is EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_202107.
It has several zipped (GZ files) files for each trading day named as
EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_202210701
EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_202210702
EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_202210703 ...
EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_202210729

I want to create a SAS dataset for each individual day and save them to a file. As far as I understand, I need a do loop to go through a month of daily TAQ data and calculate the trade duration and then just save the relevant data to a file so that each saved data set would be small, and then I have to aggregate them all up. For calculating trade duration, I am just taking the difference of the "DATETIME" variable, (ex. dif(datetime))

Until now, I have been working by making one working directory (D:\MainDataset) and doing calculations in it starting with unzipping files. But it is taking too much time and disk space. I need to create separate datasets for each trading day and save it to a file.

```
    data "D:\MainDataset" (keep= filename time exchange symbol saleCondition tradeVolume tradePrice   tradeStopStock
            tradeCorrection sequenceNumber tradeId sourceOfTrade tradeReportingFacility 
            participantTimeStamp tradeReportingFacilityTimeStamp); 
     length folderef $8 time $15. exchange $1. symbol $17. saleCondition $4. tradeStopStock $1.
            sourceOfTrade $1. tradeReportingFacility $1. 
            participantTimeStamp $15. tradeReportingFacilityTimestamp $15.;

    rc=filename(folderef,"D:\EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_202107");
    did = dopen(folderef);
    putlog did=;
    /* do k = 1 to dnum(did);   Use this to run the loop over all files in the folder */
    do k = 1 to 3;   
    filename = dread(did,k);
    putlog filename=;
    if scan(filename,-1,'.') ne 'gz' then continue;
    fullname = pathname(folderef) || '\' || filename;
    putlog fullname=;

    do while(1);
    infile archive zip filevar=fullname gzip dlm='|' firstobs=2 obs=5000000 dsd truncover eof=nextfile;
    input time exchange symbol saleCondition tradeVolume tradePrice tradeStopStock
            tradeCorrection sequenceNumber tradeId sourceOfTrade tradeReportingFacility 
            participantTimeStamp tradeReportingFacilityTimeStamp;
    output;
    end;
    nextfile:
    end;
    stop;
    run;
    Proc contents data = "D:\MainDataset";
run;

proc print data ="D:\MainDataset" (obs = 110);
run;
```

Comment: If the goal is to summarize the data before saving it you need to explain how you want to summarize it. What is a "trade duration" and how to you calculate it for a single daily dataset.  (I am assuming you meant you were having DISK SPACE issues and not MEMORY issues).

Comment: Hey Tom, I have edited the question for clarification. Can you please check? Thanks!

Comment: So it looks like you are subsetting to specific SYMBOL values.  Why not do that in the first data step?  You can also move your other new variable creation code to the same data step instead so you create all of the variables in one pass through the data instead of three.

Comment: Please explain what the resource limit you are hitting is?  How many files are you reading?  How large is each file?  How large is the end result?  To dramatically improve performance you will need to reduce the amount of data you write and re-read.

Comment: Each file is 3-4 GB, there are 23 files for 23 trading days for a month. I have to create a sas dataset for each individual day and save them to a file.  I have to write a do loop to go through a month worth of daily TAQ data and calculate everything that we want for those 30 dow stocks and then just save the relevant data to a file. The ultimate goal is to get trade duration for each of the stocks each day.

Answer (score 0):

Create code to process one file.  Probably coded as a macro that takes as input the name of the file to read and the name of the dataset to create.

```
%macro taq(infile,dataset);
data &dataset;
  infile "&infile" zip gzip dsd dlm='|' truncover firstobs=2;
  ....
run;
%mend taq;
```

Then generate a dataset with the names of the files to read and the dataset names you want to create from them.  So perhaps something like this:

```
%let ym=202107;
%let folder=D:\EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_&ym;

data taq_files;
  length dataset $32 filename $256 ;
  keep dataset filename;
  rc=filename('folder',"&folder");
  did=dopen('folder');
  do fnum=1 to dnum(did);
    filename=catx('\',"&folder",dread(did,fnum));
    dataset=scan(filename,-2,'./\');
    if 'gz'=lowcase(scan(filename,-1,'.')) then output;
  end;
  did=dclose(did);
  rc=filename('folder');
run;
```

Now that you have the list of files you can use it to call the macro once for each file.

```
data _null_;
  set taq_files;
  call execute(cats('%nrstr(%taq)(',filename,',',dataset,')'));
run;
```

The body of the macro can include the code to both read the values from the delimited files and calculate any new variables you want.  There should not be any need to do that in multiple steps based on what you have shown so far.

Your logic for converting the timestamp strings into time values seems overly convoluted.  Just use informats that match the style of the strings in the file.  For example if the strings start with 6 digits that represent HHMMSS then read that using the HHMMSS6. informat.  If the filenames has digit strings in the style YYYYMMDD then read that using the YYMMDD8. informat.

Note that a text file that is compressed to 2Gbytes will generate a dataset that is possibly 10 to 30 times that large. You might want to define the individual datasets as views instead to avoid having the use that space by changing the DATA statement:

```
data &dataset / view=&dataset ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Tom. Really appreciate. I will try to work on it.

Comment: Hello Tom, I changed the code a bit and did the following. But, the problem is, I am manually putting the file names that are in the folder. How can I get all files automatically?  @Tom

Comment: ?? I showed you the code to get the filenames using the DOPEN() and DREAD() functions. Did that not work?

Comment: I fixed it. It was having some minor issues, Many thanks